# Security concern regarding full trusted in-browser applications

Tags: silverlight, security, certificate, silverlight-5.0, trusted-application

I need a full trusted Silverlight application run in-browser mode.

For this purpose I can buy a certificate sign application and require IT to enable *AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser*. However enabling this property will allow to run all the signed Silverlight applications from other publishers. And this is a security issue, because some user data could be accessed with somebody's app over the internet.

How can I make application trusted from specific list of publishers? Is it possible to manage it with GPO (I found only managing add-on options, but it limits plugin availability for domains not app)?

Is there some workaround?

Thanks

*updated*

Only workaround I see is to limit Silverlight plugin to list of trusted domains via manage add-ons (you can do it via GPO), but in this case user is notified when plugin could not be shown and can allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask your IT if they control which certificates are trusted by the use of a global certificate store. If so, just put your certificate in this global store and it will be automatically accepted by the client machines.